# How to draw incircle (inscribed circle)?

Tags: pstricks, pst-eucl

### First Question

```
\documentclass[pstricks,12pt,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-3,-2)(2,2)
\psset{PointSymbol=none,CodeFig,CodeFigColor=red}
\pstTriangle(1,1){A}(-2,1){C}(-1,-1){B}
\pstProjection{A}{B}{C}[I]
\pstProjection{A}{C}{B}[J]
\pstProjection{C}{B}{A}[K]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to modify the size of right angle mark?

### Second Question

In  TikZ, we can draw both excircle (escribed circle) and incircle (inscribed circle) of a triangle `ABC` by passing `circum` and `in`, respectively  as follows.

```
\tkzDrawCircle[circum](A,B,C)
\tkzDrawCircle[in](A,B,C)
```

[image]

In PSTricks, what options do I have to pass to `\pstCircleABC[<options>]{A}{B}{C}{O}` to draw an incircle (of the triangle) `ABC`?  I know that we can use `\pstBissectBAC`, `\pstProjection` and `\pstCircleOA` but it is too long.

### Third Question

For the following macros,

```
\pstLineAB[Options]{A}{B}
\pstCircleOA[Options]{O}{A}
\pstCircleAB[Options]{O}{A}
\pstDistAB[Options]{A}{B}
\pstDistVal[Options]{x}
\pstInterFF[Options]{f}{g}{x0}{M}
\pstInterFL[Options]{f}{A}{B}{x0}{M}
\pstInterFC[Options]{f}{O}{A}{x0}{M}
\psGetDistanceAB[Options](x1,y1)(x2,y2){<name>}
\psGetAngleABC[Options](x1,y1)(x2,y2)(x3,y3){<symbol>}
```

what are all possible optional arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please provide *always* complete examples!

1.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-3,-2)(2,2)
\psset{PointSymbol=none,CodeFig,CodeFigColor=red,RightAngleSize=0.2}
\pstTriangle(1,1){A}(-2,1){C}(-1,-1){B}
\pstProjection{A}{B}{C}[I]
\pstProjection{A}{C}{B}[J]
\pstProjection{C}{B}{A}[K]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

2.Write an own macro `\pstInnerCircle`, which isn't too complicated

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\makeatletter
\def\pstTriangleIC{\pst@object{pstTriangleIC}}
\def\pstTriangleIC@i#1#2#3{%
  \begingroup
  \psset{PointSymbol=none,PointName=none,linestyle=none}
  \pstBissectBAC{#3}{#1}{#2}{IC_BC}
  \pstBissectBAC{#2}{#3}{#1}{IC_AB} 
  \pstInterLL{#3}{IC_AB}{#1}{IC_BC}{IC_M}
  \pstProjection[CodeFig=false]{A}{B}{IC_M}[IC_MAB] 
  \endgroup
  \begingroup
  \use@par
  \pstCircleOA{IC_M}{IC_MAB}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-3,-2)(2,2)
\psset{PointSymbol=none,CodeFig,CodeFigColor=red,RightAngleSize=0.2}
\pstTriangle(1,1){A}(-2,1){C}(-1,-1){B}
\pstProjection{A}{B}{C}[I]
\pstProjection{A}{C}{B}[J]
\pstProjection{C}{B}{A}[K]
\pstTriangleIC[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=blue]{A}{B}{C}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

3.Read the documentation

Comment: Question 2 : I am not enough ability to write \pstInnerCircle, So, I only use \pstBissectBAC, \pstProjection and \pstCircleOA.....

Comment: The macro `\pstTriangleIC` and `\pstTriangleOC` will be part of the next update of `pst-eucl`

Comment: Thank you for listening and your answer. :-))....

Comment: So \pstTriangleOC and \pstCircleABC[Options]{A}{B}{C}{O} are the different ??.

Comment: Yes, except that the origin is internally named `OC_O` for  `\pstTriangleOC`, because it has only three parameters and `\pstCircleABC` has four.

Comment: Oh, I see. That is great idea.

Comment: A problem with bullet of \pstTriangle. Until now, I just look at it ..... See my new question.