# pst-euclid: getting the inner circle

Tags: pstricks, compilation-error, pst-eucl

To draw geometrical figures I'm reading [this](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-eucl/doc/pst-eucl-doc.pdf). Now, I was testing \pstTriangleIC to get the incircle but I get a classical "undefined control sequence" error. What is wrong with my code? I think I need to set up something but I don't know what.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,spanish]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-eucl}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-2,-2)(2,2)
\pstTriangle(1,1){A}(1,0){B}(0,2){C}
\pstTriangleIC{A}{B}{C}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

p.s: I have read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464263/how-to-draw-incircle-inscribed-circle) but the solution offered was to define it as a macros. Wasn't it already defined by default?

Comment: I get no error with your code. Have you checked whether your packages are up-to-date?

Comment: @gernot I don't know. How may I check that?

Comment: Add as first line of the file `\listfiles`. Then it will list the version of all loaded packages at the end of the run. Here are some of my versions: `pstricks.tex    2020/09/18 v3.01`, `pst-eucl.sty    2020/09/29`, `article.cls    2020/04/10 v1.4m`, `LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4`

Comment: @UnPerrito  why not use tkz-euclide as in the answer below

Comment: @jsbibra because I want to know what's the problem with my code

Comment: Your TeX distribution is not up-to-date ... Do you have MiKTeX or TeXLive?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=10mm,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-2,-2)(2,2)
\pstTriangle(1,1){A}(1,0){B}(0,2){C}
\pstTriangleIC{A}{B}{C}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the above file is `hahaha.tex`, always compile with one of the following method:

- a combo 3 steps: `latex hahaha.tex` followed by `dvips hahaha.dvi` followed by `ps2pdf hahaha.ps`
- or  a single step: `xelatex hahaha.tex`.

The first method runs much much faster.

Comment: non of your methods worked on my original code. They work just when I apply the solution I linked in my post.=(

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-2,-2) grid (2,2);
    \draw [->, >=stealth] (-2,-2) -- (2,-2) node [right] {$x$};
    \draw [->, >=stealth] (-2,-2) -- (-2,2) node [above] {$y$};
        \tkzDefPoint(1,1){A}
        \tkzDefPoint(1,0){B}
        \tkzDefPoint(0,2){C}
        \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
        \tkzDrawCircle[in](A,B,C)
        \tkzLabelPoints(A,B)
        \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```